# Getting a error when trying to build a android app with expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, syntax-error

here it is:

```
Running 'gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android

[stderr] 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
* Where:
[stderr] 
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 450
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
A problem occurred evaluating script.
[stderr] 
>
[stderr] 
Calling `[node, /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js, config]` finished with an exception. Error message: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
[stderr] 
The current character read is '/' with an int value of 47
[stderr] 
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
[stderr] 
line number 1
[stderr] 
  index number 0
[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/react-native.config.js:1export default {^^^^^^SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15)    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:27)    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)    at module.exports (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/import-fresh/index.js:28:9)    at loadJs (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/loaders.js:9:18)info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
[stderr] 
^. Output: /home/expo/workingdir/build/react-native.config.js:1export default {^^^^^^SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15)    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:27)    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)    at module.exports (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/import-fresh/index.js:28:9)    at loadJs (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/loaders.js:9:18)info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] 
> Run with
[stderr] 
--scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] 
BUILD FAILED in 17s
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

Does someone know what it is?

Comment: You have a syntax error. Without seeing any code, this is next to impossible to answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

open android studio and check the actual error
you have clean the gradle and rebuild the project again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).